# How to Zip/Compress multiple folders individually in a directory using Unix?

Tags: zip

How to Zip/Compress multiple folders individually in a directory using Unix?

for example in a X: directive I have a, b, c etc..folders I have to zip them as a.zip, b.zip, and c.zip. even I dont know the folders names are like a,b, c we have to this dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you do want zip files,

```
cd /mydir/foo
find . -type d -d 1 -exec zip -r {} {} \;
```

This will create a zip file for every directory in /mydir/foo.

**EDIT:** what this commandline does (remember to never copy-paste a terminal command you don't understand, it's dangerous)

```
find . -type d -d 1 -exec xxx
```

will find all items inside . (in our case /mydir/foo), of type d for directory, then execute the command xxx

```
zip -r {} {}
```

is simply the zip command, (feel free to add the options you need, -r means recursive), using as its first (zip file) and second (source) arguments the special string {} that is fed by find with every match. \; is simply a terminator to tell find the -exec command is over, properly escaped to not be misinterpreted by the shell

Comment: Here is the updated command that will work on CentOS 6.5 `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec zip -r {} {} \;`